# Lightning Web Component - How to make unit test with multipe wire service in same Controller

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created a lightning web component to make a summary on account page for related list.

But when i try to make unit test i always get an issue with adapter id error.

I think because there is multipe asynchronous request it cause this issue.

Anyone is able to tell me if it is possible to make test on multiple wire services or what can i do to optimize my code?

**Here is my SyntheseControle.cls :**

```
public with sharing class SyntheseController {
    // Permet de compter le nombre de contact pour la page account
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getContact(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)contact FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Integer countContact = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('contact');
        return countContact;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunity(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunity FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Integer countOpportunity = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunity');
        return countOpportunity;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type B2B crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunity(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunity FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunity = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunity');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityFormated = lastCreatedOpportunity.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité de type B2B pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityB2B(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityB2B FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true];
        Integer countOpportunityB2B = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2B');
        return countOpportunityB2B;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type B2B crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunityB2B  FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunityB2B = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunityB2B');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityB2BFormated = lastCreatedOpportunityB2B.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityB2BFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité B2B Abonnement pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityB2BAbonnement(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityB2BAbo FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c != null];
        Integer countOpportunityB2BAbo = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BAbo');
        return countOpportunityB2BAbo;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité B2B Places Sèches pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityB2BPlacesSeches FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c = null];
        Integer countOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BPlacesSeches');
        return countOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montat des opportunités B2B
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityB2BAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityB2BAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true];
        Decimal amountOpportunityB2B = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BAmount');
        return amountOpportunityB2B;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montat des opportunités B2B pour les Abonnements
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityB2BAboAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityB2BAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c != null];
        Decimal amountOpportunityB2B = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BAmount');
        return amountOpportunityB2B;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montat des opportunités B2B pour les Places Sèches
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_B2B__c = true AND ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c = null];
        Decimal amountOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount');
        return amountOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montant de toutes les opportunités pour un compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Decimal amountOpportunity = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityAmount');
        return amountOpportunity;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité de type Event pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityEvent(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityEvent FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_event__c = true];
        Integer countOpportunityEvent = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityEvent');
        return countOpportunityEvent;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montant des opportunités de type Event
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityEventAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityEventAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_event__c = true];
        Decimal amountOpportunityEvent = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityEventAmount');
        return amountOpportunityEvent;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type Even crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunityEvent  FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_event__c = true];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunityEvent = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunityEvent');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityEventFormated = lastCreatedOpportunityEvent.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityEventFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter le nombre d'opportunité de type Lagardère pour un Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpportunityLagardere(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Name)opportunityLagardere FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_Lagardere__c = true];
        Integer countOpportunityLagardere = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityLagardere');
        return countOpportunityLagardere;
    }
    // Permet de calculer le montant des opportunités de type Lagardère
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getOpportunityLagardereAmount(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT SUM(Amount)opportunityLagardereAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_Lagardere__c = true];
        Decimal amountOpportunityLagardere = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('opportunityLagardereAmount');
        return amountOpportunityLagardere;
    }
    // Permet de récuperer la date de la dernière opportunitée de type Lagardère crée
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static String getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT MAX(CreatedDate)lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere  FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId AND Is_Lagardere__c = true];
        Datetime lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere = (Datetime)groupedResults[0].get('lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere');
        String lastCreatedOpportunityLagardereFormated = lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
        return lastCreatedOpportunityLagardereFormated;
    }
    // Permet de compter les activités en cours pour le Compte
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Integer getOpenActivities(String accId) {
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Subject)openactivities FROM Task WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        Integer countOpenactivities = (Integer)groupedResults[0].get('openactivities');
        return countOpenactivities;
    }
}
```

**Then my syntheseComponent.js :**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContact from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getContact';
import getOpportunityAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityAmount';
import getOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunity';
import getLastCreatedOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunity';
import getOpportunityB2B from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2B';
import getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B';
import getOpportunityB2BAbonnement from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BAbonnement';
import getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches';
import getOpportunityB2BAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BAmount';
import getOpportunityB2BAboAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BAboAmount';
import getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount';
import getOpportunityEvent from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityEvent';
import getOpportunityEventAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityEventAmount';
import getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent';
import getOpportunityLagardere from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityLagardere';
import getOpportunityLagardereAmount from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpportunityLagardereAmount';
import getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere';
import getOpenActivities from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getOpenActivities';
export default class SyntheseComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getContact, { accId: '$recordId'}) contacts;
    @wire(getOpportunity, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunity;
    @wire(getOpportunityAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityAmount;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunity, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunity;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2B, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2B;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunityB2B, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunityB2B;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BAbonnement, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BAbo;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BPlacesSeches, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BPlacesSeches;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BAmount;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BAboAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BAboAmount;
    @wire(getOpportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount;
    @wire(getOpportunityEvent, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityEvent;
    @wire(getOpportunityEventAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityEventAmount;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunityEvent, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunityEvent;
    @wire(getOpportunityLagardere, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityLagardere;
    @wire(getOpportunityLagardereAmount, { accId: '$recordId'}) opportunityLagardereAmount;
    @wire(getLastCreatedOpportunityLagardere, { accId: '$recordId'}) lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere;
    @wire(getOpenActivities, { accId: '$recordId' }) openactivities;
}
```

**Then i'm using this way in syntheseComponent.html  to rendrer :**

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Synthèse" icon-name="standard:entitlement">
    <lightning-tabset>
      <lightning-tab label="Général">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Contacts">Nb Contacts:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{contacts.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opportunités">Nb Opportunités:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunity.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant">Montant Opportunités:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Open Activities">Open Activities:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{openactivities.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date dernière opp">Dernière Opportunité:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunity.data}</b></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Opp B2B" title="2nd tab extended title">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
              <div class="slds-media__body">
                <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                  <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp B2B">Nb Opp B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{opportunityB2B.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant Opp B2B">Montant Opp B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date derniere opp B2B">Dernière Opp B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunityB2B.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp B2B Abo">Nb Opp Abo B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BAbo.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant opp abo B2B">Montant Opp Abo B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BAboAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp B2B PS">Nb Opp Places Sèches B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BPlacesSeches.data}</b></dd>
                    <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant opp PS B2B">Montant Opp Places Sèches B2B:</dt>
                    <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityB2BPlacesSechesAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  </dl>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Opp Event">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp Event">Nb Opp Event:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{opportunityEvent.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant Opp Event">Montant Opp Event:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityEventAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date derniere opp Event">Dernière Opp Event:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunityEvent.data}</b></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Opp Lagardère">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <article class="slds-tile slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Opp Lagardere">Nb Lagardère:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for first label"><b>{opportunityLagardere.data}</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Montant Opp Lagardere">Montant Opp Lagardère:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{opportunityLagardereAmount.data}€</b></dd>
                  <dt class="slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-truncate" title="Date derniere opp Event">Dernière Opportunité Lagardère:</dt>
                  <dd class="slds-item_detail slds-truncate" title="Description for second label"><b>{lastCreatedOpportunityLagardere.data}</b></dd>
                </dl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

[image: Summary Exemplae]

As you can see it is working perfectly but it seems impossible to test it.

**Here is my syntheseComponent.test.js**

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import SyntheseComponent from 'c/syntheseComponent';
import getContact from '@salesforce/apex/SyntheseController.getContact';


// Import mock data to send through the wire adapter.
const mockGetContact = require('./data/getContact.json')

// Register a test wire adapter to control @wire(getRecord)
const getRecordWireAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getContact);

describe('c-synthese-component', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('Nb Contacts:', () => {
        // Create element
        const element = createElement('c-synthese-component', {
            is: SyntheseComponent
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        getRecordWireAdapter.emit(mockGetContact);
        // Verify displayed greeting
        const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
        expect(div.textContent).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

**I have this error message while running test :**

[image: Error message from test]

If someone could help me please would be awesome.

Comment: Can you please also add you test file?

Comment: Updated with my test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the files that you have provided you have only specified a mock for the `getContact` adapter but your component has about 20 other wires that are registered.

These wires will all be activated as soon as the component renders so you need to mock them as well. If you don't mock them you'll see errors like you saw with `getOpportunities`.

Comment: By the way, if you really need all of that data, you should consider regrouping those 20 wires into a single wire for better performance.

Comment: I tried to regroup those 20 wires into a single wire, but with all those aggregations i have seems like it is not possible. Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can aggregate those results. Here's what you should do: Create an anonymous `SyntheseData` Apex class that holds the different result types. Annotate all attributes from that class with `@AuraEnabled`. Create a new Apex `@AuraEnabled` `getSynthese` method that returns `SyntheseData`. Use that method to create an instance of `SyntheseData`, load it by calling your different getter methods then, return it.

Comment: It may sound silly, but since i'm a bit new with LWC i don't really see how to make what your telling me. But i will investigate on it thanks.

Comment: no worries, ask another question for that :)

Comment: and sorry I meant inner class, not anonymous.

Comment: No problem i got an awesome answer thanks to you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please mark this one as accepted?